# applying variable to screen size on processing 3

Tags: java, processing

This code works fine in processing 2 but using variables in processing 3  in the size() function does not work, how would i go about implementing  displaywdith-100 in processing 3

```
int val, screen_increment, old_x=0, old_y=0;     
String inString;  
int lf = 10;      
void setup() 
{

  size(displayWidth-100, 600);//  The screen height is set to be 600, which matches the scaled data,
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  println(Serial.list());

  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);
  myPort.bufferUntil(lf);
  background(0);
}//setup
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `size()` with variables was always discouraged, however it was allowed because `size(displayWidth, displayHeight)` was the only way of creating a fullscreen sketch.

In Processing 3 `fullScreen()` was added, making `size(displayWidth, displayHeight)` obsolete. Thus the rules have changed from *discouraged* to *not allowed*.

However, they also added a new function `settings()`, which allows using variables with `size()`:

```
void settings() {
    size(displayWidth-100, 600);
}

void setup() 
{
    String portName = Serial.list()[0];
    println(Serial.list());

    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 115200);
    myPort.bufferUntil(lf);
    background(0);
}//setup
```

See [here](https://processing.org/reference/settings_.html):

> The settings() function is new with Processing 3.0. It's not needed in most sketches. It's only useful when it's absolutely necessary to define the parameters to size() with a variable.