# Why does processing3 forbid variable arguments to size()?

Tags: java, processing

It is known that, from Processing3, variable arguments cannot be passed to `size()` as far as you don't place the function into `settings()`. This is a fact. But **why**?

---

**Example**

```
size(100, 200); //OK
```

```
int width = 100;
int height = 200;
void settings() {
    size(width, height); //OK
}
```

```
int width = 100;
int height = 200;
size(width, height); //NG ("The size of this sketch could not be determined from your code.")
```

```
final int width = 100;
final int height = 200;
size(width, height); //NG (same as above)
```

I don't understand why the compiler cannot determine the values of `width` and `height` in the latter two examples. In these cases,

- Both of the values are hard-coded (i.e. written statically).
- Because there is no `settings()` or `setup()`, both values will never be changed at the startup phase. (Here, I use the term "startup phase" ambiguously. I don't mean any specific phase in compilation.)

so I think the examples should compile.

---

**Reference**

According to [applying variable to screen size on processing 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58480181/8776746),

> (Until processing 3, ) Using size() with variables was always discouraged

But why? This is also implied in the official changelog [Changes in 3.0](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Changes-in-3.0#things-that-may-break-your-2x-sketches)

> Do not use variables in `size()` - **This time** we **really** mean it.

The changelog tells much more information:

> In the past, the `size()` function was implemented by doing backflips behind the scenes. **Those backflips made things very fragile**, introduced cross-platform quirks that have consumed too many of my weekends, and prevented us from making wholesale performance improvements to the rendering system (higher performance, better full screen support, etc).

But how? The explanation sounds too metaphoric (too poetic).

The log also shows a safer way.

> But despair not! If you must change the size of your sketch, use `surface.setSize(w, h)` which is the one and only (safe) way to alter your sketch's size.

And this works.

```
surface.setSize(100, 200); //=> OK
```

```
int width = 100;
int height = 200;
surface.setSize(width, height); //=> OK
```

Then, why is `size()` still alive? Just for the backward compatibility? In other words, is `size()` deprecated and is it recommended that you always use `surface.setSize()` instead of `size()`?

---

**Summary**

- Why does processing3 forbid variable arguments to `size()`?
- Is there any cases where you should prefer `size()` to `surface.setSize()`?

Comment: "Why does processing3 forbid variable arguments to `size()`?" much probably it is specified that way, but how is that `Java`?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I'm asking why it is specified like that. I don't understand why the limitation (to non-variable value) is needed. *how is that Java?* Processing3 is based on Java, isn't it?

Comment: I have no idea about Processing3 - it maybe based on Java, but it is not Java, is it? Java has no restriction on having arguments for a method called `size`. And hardly this is the *best* site to ask why it was specified that way

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger It's built on java, so many questions people have while working with Processing are in fact java questions. This one looks specific to Processing, though.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger [Processing](https://processing.org/) uses Java syntax, that's the relation. But there are also plug-ins for other languages (e.g. Python). The tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>is not enough and misleading. Often it is interpreted more general than it is. So yes that is Java (syntax)

Comment: Why is my question down-voted and going to be closed? I believe I wrote logical sentences, added minimal examples and showed sufficient references.